# Do not want so many constraints in interface builder in Xcode (dealing with across the board devices)

Tags: xcode, uibutton, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints

Here's the grub.  I have a`UIButton` that I added a "Center horizontally to superview" constraint.

The button lies Y points down from the top of the superview.  When I switch through different devices in Preview mode, I want to be able to see the button stay in the center of the screen, but expand or contract (and move up/down along the center axis if need be) in order to satisfy the different device sizes.

Xcode, however, requests that I provide as many unbearable constraints as possible to satisfy all their requirements (while throwing my requirements out the door).

Initially, I put constraints on distance from the top, left, and right of the superview, and it held position but didn't increase size when I went from 4s to 6s.

I essentially don't want the button constrained to anything except the center.  I want it ADAPTABLE.

How do I go about making it adaptable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have constraints that define 4 attributes, x position, y position, width, and height.  So if you created a constraint to center horizontally, you've added one of those.  If you want it to be in the center on the y axis, you need to add another constraint to center vertically.  Then the content of the button will create constraints behind the scenes for you for width and height (just large enough to show the content), but if you want the button to size proportionally to the size of the device, you'll need a constraint between the width of the button and the width of the top-level view, same with height.